# Polymorphic object members

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have the following problem. I have a base class and several classes inheriting from it. All those classes are sharing a very similar interface and will most probably not be required to overload most of the shared methods.

However, all of them are using different member objects that are derived from each other and share a very similar interface too.

```
class BaseClass
{
    protected:
        Com* com;

    public:
        void setReady()
        {
            com->setReady();
        }
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    protected:
        DerivedCom* com;
}

class Derived2Class : BaseClass
{
    protected:
        Derived2Com* com;
}
```

How can I enable `DerivedClass` to have `setReady()` run its version of `com` instead of the one inherited from `BaseClass`?

Comment: Why do you need to have the multiple pointers? Can a `DerivedClass` have both a `Com*` and a `DerivedCom*` at the same time? If not, then reuse the member at the base level.

Comment: No, it can't. How would one do that then?

Comment: See the answer by d909b. Add on top of that any function in `DerivedXClass` can use a pointer cast to transform the `Com*` into the appropriate `DerivedCom*` for a richer interface

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Construct your instances with different implementations of Com. (Assuming DerivedCom implements Com)

```
class BaseClass
{
    protected:
        Com* com;

    public:
        BaseClass(Com* c = new Com) : com(c) 
        {}

        void setReady()
        {
            com->setReady();
        }
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public:
        DerivedClass() : BaseClass(new DerivedCom) 
        {}
}

class Derived2Class : BaseClass
{
    public:
        Derived2Class() : BaseClass(new Derived2Com) 
        {}
}
```

Comment: +1 Simple and to the point: If you don't have multiple `Com` objects, why keep multiple pointers?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Uhm, won't the base ctors allocate `com`, only to have the derived ctor override it and thus leak memory?

Comment: @NikosC.: you are assuming that the pointer is allocated in construction. If you read the code in the answer above you will see that only the most derived type is allocating and passing it up the hierarchy. For each complete type there is a single allocation. It could even be the case that none of the constructors really allocate and the pointer is passed from client code. The more interesting question is how to use the `Com*` in the rest of the `DerivedClass` functions as a `DerivedCom*`, and `static_cast`/`dynamic_cast` would be an answer.

Comment: I don't quite understand why your constructors for `DerivedClass` are named after `BaseClass` and how that would affect instantiating the objects.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas That looks suspicious to me. The internal `com` object is exposed that way. Perhaps a protected constructor would be better. Access in derived classes is quite easy though; all you need is a new `private` member: `derivedCom(static_cast<derivedCom*>(com)` so that there's no need to cast all the time throughout the code.

Comment: Did you mean... `Derived2Class() : BaseClass(new Derived2Com)`?

Comment: Hm, it kind of makes sense to me but it won't work properly: http://codepad.org/C6Fv5ho6

Comment: Gah, setReady needs to be virtual. :-D

Comment: Fixed the constructors (they cannot initialize the member of the base directly, but they can pass the pointer upstream. @NikosC. I am not sure I understand the question. The constructor for the base is accessible, but external code cannot use that to construct a `Derived` object, only a `Base`. Whether a `Base` can be constructed directly or not is a different design issue (it can go either way and still make sense)

Comment: Hm... and what if one of the affected class members is a template? The ctor's signature doesn't fit...

Comment: Hm this concept seems to break down once I am trying to use specific `DerivedCom` methods: http://codepad.org/1EPtNuO3 Any ideas?

Comment: @NilsWerner You redefined `com` in the subclass `DerivedClass`. This is how you should be doing it: [new codepad](http://codepad.org/YUXWsYnI)

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is to introduce a `getCom()` protected virtual function, that returns a `Com*` or `Com&`:

```
virtual Com* getCom()
{ return this->com; }
```

The child classes can override it and return their own Com-derived instance. Your `setReady()` function can then be implemented as:

```
void setReady()
{
    getCom()->setReady();
}
```

Your `com` member can then be made `private`, btw.

The drawback with this solution is that you'll have multiple `Com`-derived instances in the child classes.

Comment: While the claim of simplicity is ok (although I won't go as far as saying *simplest*, it is simple), I am a bit less inclined to call this the *most widely used*. The design has a core issue: a `DerivedClass` has a useless `Com*` through the base, which makes this a design issue. A better solution would be to reuse that pointer (which is protected) down through the hierarchy (See d909b's answer).

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas You're right. It's subjective; just because I see it used most often doesn't make it so generally. I'll remove that bit.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a class template might help you:

```
class BaseClass
{
protected:
    Com* com;

public:
    virtual void setReady()
    {
        com->setReady();
    }
};

template<typename T>
class ComDerived : public BaseClass {
protected:
    T* com;
public:
    void setReady()
    {
        com->setReady();
    }
};

class DerivedClass : public ComDerived<DerivedCom>
{

};

class Derived2Class : public ComDerived<Derived2Com>
{

};
```

Comment: In this case, wouldn't setReady have to be virtual?  Also, I don't know the standard well enough to know if this would give you multiple Com objects in a DerivedClass...

Comment: @RobertMason you're right, I based my example in OP's code; it should be virtual. As for the multiple `com` members, there is no problem about it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not templated mother class?

```
template <typename T>
class BaseClass
{
    protected:
        T* com;

    public:
        void setReady()
        {
            com->setReady();
        }
};

class DerivedClass : BaseClass<DerivedCom>
{
};

class Derived2Class : BaseClass<Derived2Com>
{
};
```

Comment: *Why not template...* In general you don't want to do that, as now `DerivedClass` and `Derived2Class` are unrelated types that cannot be used polymorphically.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: They can still be used polymorphically, just only statically so, thanks to template argument deduction.  Consider `template <class T> void foo(BaseClass<T> base) { base.setReady(); }`: this is callable as `foo(obj);` so long as the actual type of obj can be deduced by the compiler at compile time.  Although this limits the flexibility somewhat, in some cases (for example, in a dependency injection framework) this can be enough.

Answer (score 0):

To build on d909b's answer, I'd do something like:

```
class BaseClass {
private:
   virtual Com * alloc_com() {
      return new Com;
   }
   Com * com;
public:
   BaseClass() : com(alloc_com()) {}
   void setReady() {
      com->setReady();
   }
};

class DerivedClass {
private:
   virtual Com * alloc_com() override {
      return new DerivedCom;
   }
};

class Derived2Class {
private:
   virtual Com * alloc_com() override {
      return new Derived2Com;
   }
};
```

This works as long as DerivedCom publicly inherits from Com AND when Com has a virtual destructor.  If Com does not have a virtual destructor, you also need to have a virtual dealloc_com function.  Otherwise, you need to use a template or CRTP pattern, and then you're limited to cases where you are able to deduce the type of the object at compile time.  If you know these are your only cases though, using templates will allow you to use the interface without adding virtual function call overhead.