# Template polymorphism

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

I've recently received a [very good answer as how to overload specific class members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454756/c-polymorphic-object-members) by deriving classes.

The issue now is that one of the members is in fact templated with specializations either being `BaseClass`, `DerivedClass` or `Derived2Class`

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;


template<class T>
class Queue
{
    public:
        Queue();
        Queue(T*);
}

class Com
{
    public:
        virtual void setReady()
        {
            cout << "Com" << endl;
        }
};

class DerivedCom : public Com
{
    public:
        void setReady()
        {
            cout << "DCom" << endl;
        }
};

class Derived2Com : public Com
{
    public:
        void setReady()
        {
            cout << "D2Com" << endl;
        }
};

class BaseClass
{
    protected:
        Com* com;
        Queue<BaseClass>* queue;

    public:
        BaseClass(Com* c = new Com, Queue<BaseClass>* q = new Queue<BaseClass>) : com(c), queue(q)
        {
        }

        void setReady()
        {
            com->setReady();
        }
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
    public:
        DerivedClass() : BaseClass(new DerivedCom, new Queue<DerivedClass>) 
        {
        }
};

class Derived2Class : public BaseClass
{
    public:
        Derived2Class() : BaseClass(new Derived2Com, new Queue<Derived2Class>) 
        {}
};

int main()
{
    BaseClass* base = new Derived2Class();

    base->setReady();
    return 0;
}
```

I can, without problem, "overload" simple classes like `Com`, `DerivedCom` and `Derived2Com` but the constructor signature of `BaseClass` won't fit to the type the deriving classes are trying to send it.

Comment: If this is just simple mistake that `*` is missing before `q` in `BaseClass(Com* c = new Com, Queue<BaseClass> q = new Queue<BaseClass>)` then correct it. But this will not solve your problems...

Comment: The crux is that `Queue<DerivedClass>` does not derive from `Queue<BaseClass>`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Queue<BaseClass>* queue;` you should have `Queue<BaseClass*> queue;` or, even better, `Queue<std::unique_ptr<BaseClass>>` and initialize it only in the base constructor:

```
BaseClass(Com* c = new Com, Queue<BaseClass*> q = Queue<BaseClass*>()) : com(c), queue(q)
{
}
```

However having the `BaseClass` hold a collection of itself as a member is a code smell. I'd re-think that part.

The reason it's not working is that `Queue<BaseClass>` and `Queue<DerivedClass>` are **completely different classes**.

Comment: `Queue` never instantiates the class it's being handled, it's just a wrapper for a method invocation queue: http://pastie.org/5401518. That way I can postpone method calls, i.e. using `queue->push(&BaseClass::setReady);` and call them later on using `queue->pop()`

Comment: @NilsWerner I don't see how that's relevant.

Comment: Yup, it's not. I just wanted to show that there is a reason why I am doing it.

Answer (score -1):

You should actually have `Queue<BaseClass*>* queue = new Queue<BaseClass*>();` This declares a Queue pointer of type BaseClass pointer on the heap and allows you to use the pointer notation you mentioned above as `queue->push(&BaseClass::setReady);` and such...

Comment: -1 because there's no need for `queue` to be allocated with new.

Comment: and while that may be true.....I was just saying he needed to referring to a pointer to the queue since he was using pointer notation, so Im sorry, but it MUST be a pointer in order for that to work, much less compile. I appreciate the minus 1 for you misunderstanding my response...

Answer (score -1):

Following [an answer found elsewhere I](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469401/replacing-templated-function-pointer-by-generic-type) changed the concept of class `Queue` to be template-less.