# Polymorphic Member Variable

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, polymorphism

I got an elegant answer yesterday for my question regarding [polymorphic object members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454756/polymorphic-object-members).

But now I am facing the problem that the variable isn't really behaving the way I expected it to. The following code is being used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;


class Com
{
    public:
        virtual void setReady()
        {
            cout << "Com" << endl;
        }
};

class DerivedCom : public Com
{
    public:
        void setReady()
        {
            cout << "DCom" << endl;
        }

        void somethingElse()
        {
            cout << "else" << endl;
        }

};

class BaseClass
{
    public:
        Com* com;

    public:
        BaseClass(Com* c = new Com) : com(c)
        {
        }

        virtual void setReady()
        {
            com->setReady();
        }
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
    // the call to somethingElse() won't compile if I leave out this declaration
    protected:
        DerivedCom* com;

    public:
        DerivedClass() : BaseClass(new DerivedCom) 
        {
        }

        void setReady()
        {
            // This line causes a segfault if I put in the declaration earlier
            this->com->setReady();

            // This line won't compile if I leave out the declaration earlier
            this->com->somethingElse();
        }
};

int main()
{
    DerivedClass* inst = new DerivedClass();

    inst->setReady();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, that `DerivedClass::com` is in fact of type `DerivedCom` but I can't access any `DerivedCom`-specific methods as the compiler won't find them. If I put in an extra re-declaration `DerivedCom* com`, the compiler will find the methods but I get segmentation faults.

Comment: Nowhere in this code do I see a virtual dtor which is essential if you want cascading dtor calls when you call delete on base class.

Comment: This is just a proof of concept. I figured I didn't need dtors.

Comment: well, [polymorphism] tag without at least `virtual ~Com{}` looks pretty weird.

Comment: @NilsWerner: This was already mentioned in the comments of the original question (in particular the third comment to the question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove that extra declaration.

If you are sure that a `Com*` is a `DerivedCom*` then you can `static_cast` it.

```
static_cast<DerivedCom*>(this->com)->somethingElse();
```

This will likely crash it you're wrong however. So if you are not sure then you can `dynamic_cast` it

```
DerivedCom* dcom = dynamic_cast<DerivedCom*>(this->com);
if (dcom)
    dcom->somethingElse();
```

`dynamic_cast` will return NULL if the object isn't of the type you asked for.

Comment: It works, interesting! Is there any way to make the static cast once and then simply use `this->com` in the rest of the class?

Comment: no, the static-cast pointer you're making is locally scoped. You'd have to keep that redeclaration to be able to use this->com at all places in the class

Comment: Sure just declare a member variable (but called something different from  `com`) and initialise it in your constructor. But I think I would rather static_cast it each time, it's not good to duplicate information.

Comment: Like... declaring `DerivedCom* com` and executing `this->com = static_cast<DerivedCom*>(BaseClass::com);` in the constructor. Or is that just an ugly hack?

Comment: That won't change the type of com, it will still be a Com.

Comment: Provided you own the code, you could also add a stub (an empty body) implementation of `somethingElse()` to BaseClass, or declare `somethingElse()` pure-virtual in BaseClass.

Comment: @WhozCraig But then my `BaseClass` would be required to know of all the derivations my `DerivedClass`es will have.

Comment: Certainly. If this is a general condition (base + derived-specials) then static_cast<> or dynamic_cast<> will be your ultimate answer one way or another. I only brought it up as a solution to get around *a* member function addition, not *all* of them =P

Comment: If performance is not an issue (it rarely is) I would suggest offering an accessor to the pointer and make use of covariance: `virtual Com* Base::getCom() { return com; }` (probably protected?), then implement `virtual DerivedCom* Derived::getCom() { return static_cast<DerivedCom*>(com); }`, then use the accessor in the rest of the code. The extra cost is a bit higher than a dynamic function call, but that should not matter in general. If you need performance do the casts on each function, once in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the segmentation faults is that you **arent declaring the variable again** with a different type, you are actually **defining a new pointer** in the derived class, one that is never initialized. Thus `this->com->...` will access the derived class `com` and crash since it is an **uninitialized pointer**.

What you are trying to do though, is to **change the type of the member pointer**. You could do that by **making the type of the member pointer as a template variable**, as follows

```
template <class ComType>
class BaseClassTemplate
{
    ComType* com;
    ...;
};

typedef BaseClassTemplate<Com> BaseClass;

class DerivedClass : public BaseClassTemplate<DerivedCom>
{
    ...;
};
```

However this makes the base class a template, so to get it as you want it, you need to make an instantiation of `BaseClass<Com>` to get your version of base class. You can either make it a derived class or just a typedef as i have shown.